# HTML form input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getelementbyid

I have this javascript code:

```
function othername() {
    var input = document.getElementById("formName".value);
    alert('Thanks for filling that out,' + ' ' +  input + '!') 
}
```

And this html code:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="text" id="formName"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="othername();" />
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="text" id="formName"/>
  <input type="submit" onclick="othername();" />
</form>
<script>
 function othername() {
  var input = document.getElementById("formName").value;
  alert('Thanks for filling that out, ' + input + '!') 
 }
</script>
```

Notice the closing parens.

Comment: To add to this, the id for the form is `form` and not just `formName`.

Comment: @MKemp The ID is actually correct, we're interested in the value of the input field AFAIK.

Comment: Derp, you are correct :) I glanced over that part of the HTML.

Comment: lol, thanks. had a feeling it was something as simple as this.

Comment: @ppajer Is there a way to make 'input' a 'website wide' variable? As in it can be used in other pages, with the same value.

Comment: @Hkessel1 You could save it [as a cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) after the button is clicked. For anything more complex than storing a few (public) values, you would need some sort of backend and session management to persist user data though.

Comment: @ppajer Yeah, I guess I would have to bring something like php or mysql into the scene.